# Serializing and deserializing interfaces in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

### Scenario:

I have two Java applications - `Master` and `Slave`. `Master` needs to send to the Slave instance of class `DEParamSet` via socket.

### DEParamSet:

```
    public class DEParamSet implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8151790178483218232L;
        public final float CR, F;
        public final int NP, D;
        public final Specimen specimen;
        public final IOptimizationFunction optFunction;

        // Constructor and some methods....
        ... some code ...
    }
```

### IOptimizationFunction:

```
    public interface IOptimizationFunction extends Serializable {
        public double evaluate(Object[] values);
    }
```

`Master` creates instance of this class, serializes it and sends it via socket to the `Slave`.

### Fragment of code:

```
    // Create objective function
    IOptimizationFunction opt = new IOptimizationFunction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167105656008707046L;

        @Override
        public double evaluate(Object[] params) {
            return (double) params[0] * (double) params[1];
        }
    };
    // Create instance of DEParamSet with objective function defined above.
    ...some code to create it...
    // Start thread, which serializes the instance and sends it via socket.
    ...some code...
```

### Question:

On the `Master`, everything works fine. No exception. `Slave` receives data and tries to deserialize it. The following exception is thrown

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

There is no error in `DEParamSet` class, because if I create it with optimization function = null, then `Slave` deserializes it with no problem. I tried to serialize instance into the file in the `Master` and then deserialize it as well. And it works. But `Slave` unable to deserialize instance, if it constains implementation of optimization function. Of course, slave contains definition of `IOptimizationFunction` interface.

Please help.

**Edit**
I have the class `TestingFunction`. The class looks like this:

```
    public abstract class TestingFunctions {
        public static double schwefel(Object[] params) {

            double res = 0d;
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                res += (-1) * (double) params[i] * Math.sin(Math.sqrt(Math.abs((double) params[i])));
            }
            return res;
        }

        public static double rastrigin(Object[] params) {
            double res = 0d;
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                res += Math.pow((double) params[i], 2) - 10 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (Double) params[i]);
            }
            return res * 2 * params.length;
        }
    }
```

Each of these functions has returned type `double` and parameter is `array of object`. This is equal to the method `double evaluate(Object[] params)` in `IOptimizationFunction` interface. So, my vision is, that master create object of `DEParamSet`, which will contains some parameters and concrete implementation of interface `IOptimizationFunction`. For example, one of possible implementation is this:

```
    IOptimizationFunction opt = new IOptimizationFunction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167105656008707046L;

        @Override
        public double evaluate(Object[] params) {
            return TestingFunctions.rastrigin(params);
        }
    };
```

It this case, Rastrigin's function is called. But which function will be called, this defines user at runtime. He can selects from function, which are in the `TestingFunction` class.

Comment: You should describe better the error. What class is not found in ClassNotFoundException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IOptimizationFunction opt = new IOptimizationFunction() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167105656008707046L;

    @Override
    public double evaluate(Object[] params) {
        return (double) params[0] * (double) params[1];
    }
};
```

The above lines create an instance of an anonymous inner class. Then, this instance is serialized and sent to the slave. Since the Slave doesn't have this anonymous inner class in its classpath, it can't deserialize it.

Make sure to put all the classes shared by the client and the server in a common project, and to have the jar file produced by this project in the classpath of both applications (master and slave).

Comment: I have created new Java project, which contains all shared classes and interfaces. From this project I created .jar file and this jar file is the external library for Slave and Master. But still the same exception.

Comment: But have you transformed this anonymous inner class into a top-level class part of the common project? The problem is with this anonymous inner class.

Comment: Yes. The common projects contains the definition of interface. But concrete implementation of method in interface (IOptimizationFunction) is still in the master. Maybe, I am confused right now... Common projects contains a package, in this package is definition of interface. Master uses this common project. Master creates a concrete interface (it defines body of method of interface) and then send it to the slave. Is it OK?

Comment: You don't seem to understand that the concrete class implementing the interface must be known by the two parties. What is serialized is the state of the object, and the name of the class. If the receiver doesn't have the class, how could it reconstruct an object having the same state and the same implementation as the receiver? Transform the anonymous class into a top-level class, make it part of the common project, and don't serialize instances of anonymous classes inly known by the sender.

Comment: I can not transform anonymous class into a top-level class. My interface IOptimizationFunction is some function, which body may be different. User select from GUI concrete function and then I can create concrete implementation of IOptimizationFunction. I can not have in Common project defined body of evalute(Object[] values) method. Master defines this method at runtime - I have some implementations in static class (contains some methods). One of these method is called via interface IOptimizationFunction - but which function is determined in runtime.

Comment: The TestFunc is my static class, which contains method like this: public double nameOfFunc(Object[] val). At runtime, one of these method is called from interface. Interaface method evalute then looks like this: return TestFunc.nameOfFunct(values). But "nameOfFunc" selects an user.

Comment: I can't comment on code without seeing it. What's sure is that the receiver can't create a class from thin air. It needs to have the byte-code. So the class of the object sent by the sender must be in the classpath of the receiver. There's no way around it. You're not generating byte-code dynamically, right? So the classes of the sender could be in the classpath of the receiver.

Comment: I edited my question. I added some more information. But I think that only way, how can I solve it, is create classes in common project, which will implements IOptimizationFunction and they will contains concrete implementations of evalute(Object[] args) method.

Comment: That's what I'm telling you from the start.

Comment: OK. I am very sorry for my incomprehension. I did not use this solution, because I wanted to give to user a possibility, that he can specify his custom function - he gives the .jar file with class with custom function, I check via reflection if his class implements my interface and then I use it. This would be able to do only in master. But in current situation, the common project must be edited for adding some new function. I am not sure if I described my original intent clearly...

Comment: As long as the jar containing the custom IOptimizationFunction implementation is also available at the receiver end, that will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I understand right now. But this solution has for me one little disadvantage. Now, common project contains for example 5 implementations. I can use it all without problem. But what can I do if user wants to use his custom implementation? He has a .jar file which contains class, that implements my interface. I can check via reflection that his class implements my interface. If yes, I can use  his implementation of function. But I am not able to dynamically modify the common .jar file to add user's implementation, right?

Comment: Tell the user to add his jar file in the classpath of the master AND in the classpath of the slave.